# How to redirect to an action in another area in ASP.NET Core 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I tried the following code to redirect from an action in the default area to an action in the ControlPanel area:

```
return RedirectToAction(nameof(Areas.ControlPanel.Controllers.HomeController.Index),
                            nameof(Areas.ControlPanel.Controllers.HomeController).Replace("Controller", ""),
                            new { area = nameof(Areas.ControlPanel) });
```

but it produces this url in the browser:
https://localhost:44360/Home/Index?area=ControlPanel

while it want it to be: https://localhost:44360/ControlPanel/Home/Index

Any ideas how I can fix it?

Comment: If you go to https://localhost:44360/ControlPanel/Home/Index in your browser, does it work?

Comment: Yes, it does work.

Comment: if I try return RedirectToAction("Index", "ControlPanel/Home"); it works. But I don't think that's the right way to do it.

Comment: Have you specified `[Area("ControlPanel")]` on your `HomeController` that should live within the `ControlPanel` area?

Comment: Yes, I have done that too.

Comment: It sounds like you have everything covered - If you're really struggling with this, you might want to consider creating a *simple* repro for others to run locally, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-use-an-area-in-asp-net-core). The Home controller in the ControlPanel area must look like this:

```
namespace Solution.Areas.ControlPanel.Controllers
{
    [Area(nameof(ControlPanel))]
    [Route(nameof(ControlPanel) + "/[controller]")]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index() => View();
    }
}
```

the important part being [Route(nameof(ControlPanel) + "/[controller]")].

Comment: Thanks! I was having exactly this same problem, and your solution worked! Thanks for referring to the article as well.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that your areas route is registered first:

```
 app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
        routes.MapRoute(name: "areas", template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        routes.MapRoute(name: "default", template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
```

Alternative define controller level routes for each area controller:

```
[Area("[areaname]")]
[Route("[areaname]/[controller]")]
public class YourController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index() => View();
}
```

All else fails make explicitly use a routing:

```
var url = Url.RouteUrl("areas", new { controller = "[controller]", action = "Index", area = "[areaname]" });
                        return Redirect(url);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your statement isn't completely clear,
Try this:

```
return RedirectToAction("action", "controller", new { area = "area" });
```

Comment: This is basically my code without using nameof method. Anyway I even tried it your way and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same situation, After a lot of tries, I fix it.

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(name: "areas", template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                routes.MapRoute(name: "default", template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
```

Area template should be first.
Now you can redirect to area to area like

```
return RedirectToAction("action name", "controller name", new { area = "area name" });
```

Answer (score 0):

The full solution that worked for me

1. Make sure to register area routes before(!) regular routes
2. Add Area and Route attributes for an area controller
3. Add Route attribute for every action of an area controller.

**Examples for registering an area route:**

*Already mentioned by others*

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{ routes.MapRoute(name: "areas", template: "area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
  routes.MapRoute(name: "default", template: "controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

*another way to register area route*

```
app.MapAreaControllerRoute(
  "Route_name",
  "AreaName",
  "Areas/{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
  new { action = "Index" } 
);
```

**Example for area controller attributes:**

*Already mentioned by others*

```
[Area("[areaname]")]
[Route("[areaname]/[controller]")]
public class YourController : Controller
{
   
}
```

**Example for action attribute of an area controller:**

```
[HttpGet("[action]")]
public ActionResult ChangePassword()
{
  return View();
}
```